# Key combination Ctrl+[Period] not working Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, 22.04

Recently my keyboard starts getting crazy, everytime I press the key combination Ctrl + [Period] it prints the letter `e`, and then if I try to re-press the combination it deletes the `e` letter. I tried to reinstall the keyboard layout (which in my case is the `IT` layout) but even if I'm using the `US` it gets the same problem. [example of the letter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQAtD.png)

I noticed that right after the installation, the system the keyboard was mapped correctly, I think the problems came out after the installation of VSCode, maybe the problem is caused by some "under the hood" feature of VSCode? But sounds strange because it affects the whole system, even if the VSCode is completely closed.

P.S.: I have already re-install completely the system but the problem pops out again.

P.P.S.: When I tried to map the new keybinding (setting ctrl+[period], VSCode just tells me that the combination is [unknown keymapping value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2hZw.png))

Does anybody have some idea about this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 21.10 keyboard shortcut Ctrl+. changed - How to disable or change](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370022/ubuntu-21-10-keyboard-shortcut-ctrl-changed-how-to-disable-or-change)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Nowadays IBus uses that shortcut by default to access emojis.

If you need the shortcut for other purposes, you can run `ibus-setup` in a terminal window, select the *Emoji* tab, and change the *Emoji annotation* shortcut to your liking.

Comment: Yes man, thank you so much. Just switch the default key (Ctrl+[period] to another one) and everything returns as before. kudos

Comment: Emojis... _That_ was the problem. Bugged me for months. I'm getting too old for this world.

Comment: Anyone know who to contact about this change? Was it Ubuntu devs who picked these keymaps, or IBus devs? This should be reverted - the keybindings chosen conflict with too many keybindings in too many apps.

Comment: @holocronweaver: That happened [upstream](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/commit/b952d30a). Don't expect it to be easy to change — any sensible shortcut will conflict with something.