# Is there any update in keyboard shortcuts in 22.04 for key: ctl + .?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 22.04

After updating ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04(LTS), a new keyboard shortcut is added (CTL +.). when I press those combinations **e̲** is appear and after writing something then press enter it disappears and does nothing just enter the word after writing **e̲**.

1. Is anyone experienced this?
2. I don't what is the intention to add this?
3. Can I change those combinations?

Comment: This work for you : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370022/ubuntu-21-10-keyboard-shortcut-ctrl-changed-how-to-disable-or-change/1370032#1370032 ?

Comment: Thank you this works for me.